# How to inject an interface that is part of the framework using custom class in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am working on a SilverStripe project. Project SilverStripe version is 4.4.4. In my project, I am trying to replace a class that injected for an interface. Both the interface and the class are part of the framework.

In the framework code, it has the following class

```
class NaturalFileIDHelper implements FileIDHelper
```

As you can see, the NaturalFileIDHelper is implementing the FileIDHelper interface. What I want to do is that I want to replace all the NaturalFileIDHelper instances with my customer class called CustomFileIDHelper class that is also implementing the FileIDHelper interface.

This is what I did.

I created a custom class called, CustomFileIDHelper that is implementing the FileIDHelper interface.

Then I added the following code snippet within the mysite.yml.

```
  SilverStripe\Assets\FilenameParsing\FileIDHelper:
    class: CustomFileIDHelper
```

Then I rebuild the project. But my project is still using the NaturalFileIDHelper class that comes with the framework. It seems like the CustomFileIDHelper class is not used.

How can I get it working? Is it possible to do that?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot inject other interfaces, as this is core PHP functionality. With Injector you can replace concrete classes / instances as Conny answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to replace all the `NaturalFileIDHelper` instances with my customer class called `CustomFileIDHelper` class

If you want to replace all `NaturalFileIDHelper` instances, then that's the class you should override (not the `FileIDHelper`). Also the `.yml` config you have needs to be passed to the `Injector`. (https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/extending/injector/)

```
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector:
  SilverStripe\Assets\FilenameParsing\NaturalFileIDHelper:
    class: CustomFileIDHelper
```

But this will only work if the object is instantiated through the `ClassName::create()` function, and I found this piece of code in the framework:

```
(LegacyThumbnailMigrationHelper.php)
$defaultFileIDHelper = new NaturalFileIDHelper(), // Injector is not called here.
```

You will need to override the classes which call `new NaturalFileIDHelper()` and modify it to `NaturalFileIDHelper::create()`, you're able to call `::create()` because the `NaturalFileIDHelper` class have the `use Injectable;` trait.

Also instead of going through the troubles of overriding classes which call `new NaturalFileIDHelper()`, you can create a pull request to the framework repository with your `NaturalFileIDHelper::create()` changes instead, as it would be an improvement to the current framework code (it enables the use of dependency injection).